# Angular focus on select element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to programmatically focus on a `select` element with `angular`. Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('microwaveRef') microwaveElement: ElementRef
this.microwaveElement.nativeElement.focus()
```

On the `HTML` side:

```
<mat-form-field class='login-full-width'>
    <mat-label>Microwave</mat-label>
    <mat-select #microwaveRef [formControl]="microwaveFormControl" required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of microwave" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf='microwaveFormControl.hasError("required")'>
        Please select an option for the Microwave field
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

This has worked well with a text input field, but with the select I receive this error:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined`

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's undefined because `nativeElement` doesn't exist directly on a `mat-select`.
An alternative is to use to `focused` property on the `mat-select` and set it to true yourself:

```
this.microwaveElement.focused = true
```

I provided a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-nyqas9) example to demonstrate this.

---

### Edit:

Actually, the `mat-select` has a `focus()` function of its own, so you can use:

```
this.microwaveElement.focus();
```

Or even:

```
this.microwaveElement.open();
```